# delete one element in a list in sharedPreferences

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to delete an element in my `favoriteList` here but this doesn't seem to be working. I've looked on the web but couldn't find anything related to this. They were all about how to clear sharedPreferences or delete a key.

```dart
 Future<void> removeFav(String articleId) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    favoriteList = prefs.getStringList('favoriteList');
    if (favoriteList != null) {
      await prefs.remove('${favoriteList!.where((id) => id == articleId)}'); //I'm guessing id here returns an element of this list..??
      print('unfavorited');
      setState(() {
        isFavorite = false;
      });
    } else {
      print('favoriteList was null');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first remove the item from the list:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// get the list, if not found, return empty list.
var favoriteList = prefs.getStringList('favoriteList')?? [];

// remove by articleId
favoriteList.removeWhere((item) => item == articleId);
```

Then, saved the changed `favoriteList` back to sharedPreferences:

```
prefs.setStringList('favoriteList', favoriteList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do these steps to save List of object in `SharedPreferences`:

- convert your object to map → `toMap()` method
- encode your map to string → `encode(...)` method
- save the string to `shared preferences`

for restoring your object:

- decode shared preference string to a map → `decode(...)` method
- use `fromJson()` method to get your object

So in this case I think you should restore the list from `shared preference` and modify list and then save new list in `shared preference`.